# SQL says no active transaction even though I created one

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, sql-server-2019

Using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 6.0.5, with .NET 6, I'm doing multiple database operations inside of a transaction.  When I call `CommitAsync`, it fails saying:

> Cannot issue SAVE TRANSACTION when there is no active transaction.

How is there no active transaction when I've clearly created one?

```cs
var task = await Context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);

try {
    var newEntity = ...

    ... Multiple database operations ...
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    ... Other DB operations that now make use of the just created objects.
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    await task.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);

    return newEntity;
} catch (Exception) {
    await task.RollbackAsync(cancellationToken);
    throw;
}
```

I'm creating multiple object in different tables that reference each other, and calling other people's code that might be doing a save operation of its own, thus the transaction.

Comment: How do you create the `cancellationToken`? Perhaps it has cancelled?

Comment: It's using the `CancellationToken` provided to the HttpPut controller method, and then I just pass that to this method.  It's definitely not getting canceled though.  I stuck a `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` right before the commit, just to be sure.

Comment: I'm guessing someone somewhere is calling `Context.Database.CurrentTransaction.Commit` when they shouldn't

Comment: @Charlieface This is the only spot in the entire codebase that does anything with a transaction. I did a global find for Commit and it's just this one spot.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely I tracked this down to SQL server corruption. I had renamed a table and for some reason, if I saved changes to that table, it was internally (in the SQL server) trying to use that old name.  I nuked the table and recreated and then I had no more transaction issues.

Comment: I'm guessing there was an exception which rolled back the transaction, but you swallowed it somehow